# Need to ignore empty variable values for Computed Field when multiplying

Tags: entities

In my entityform, different fields appear based on choices (dependencies). Two appear at once. I'm multiplying the values using a Computed field. All works if the variables have a value. I have 8 fields I want to multiply, but ignore the empty values. Can't set field defaults to 0 (wrecks multiplication) or 1 (messes with totals).

The following warning appears for each empty field; here it's "line 1" for the 1st variable/field. No warning for those that have a value.

> Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in eval() (line 1 of /home/content/67/10793667/html/sites/all/modules/computed_field/computed_field.module(466) : eval()'d code).

How can I instruct the computed field to ignore the empty fields?

Here is my Computed Code (PHP).

```
$howmany = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_how_many')));
$price1 = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_reg_price1')));
$price2 = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_sale_price2')));
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $howmany*$price1*$price2;
```

I tried adding this after the `$price2` line, but it didn't work.

```
if ($price2 == null) {
    $price2 = 1;
}
```

I tried this too, and it didn't work.

```
if (!empty($price2)) {
  $price2 = 1;
}
else {
  $price2 = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_sale_price2')));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both @Neo's answer and @danielesus's question shows PHP code that will throw errors. @Neo, `empty()` only works with variables before PHP 5.5. Both: `array_pop` requires a variable or something returned by a reference-returning-function which `field_get_items` is not.

Now let's consider what `field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_how_many')` returns: it returns an array indexed by delta where the values are `field_column  => value`. You can do

```
if ($all_items = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_how_many')) {
  $item = reset($all_items);
  $value = reset($item);
}
```

as there's no need to actually modify the array with `array_pop` but also you can use your knowledge about Field API and know the actual column name which I suspect will be `value` here (would be `tid` for a taxonomy reference field for example) and that `$delta` is, if you have a field with cardinality 1 is actually 0:

```
$value = NULL;
if ($all_items = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_how_many')) {
  $value = $all_items[0]['value'];
}
```

Fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
$howmany = !empty(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_how_many')) ? array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_how_many'))) : 1; 

$price1 = !empty(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_reg_price1')) ? array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_reg_price1'))) : 1; 

$price2 = !empty(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_sale_price2')) ? array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_sale_price2'))) : 1; 

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $howmany*$price1*$price2;
```

If this still does not work, Please try to inspect the structure of the stuff returned by field_get_items(). I am pretty sure the issue lies in returning a null from the fist array_pop.

In order to inspect the structure, add these lines to your compute code after enabling and installing devel module:

dpm(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_how_many'));
dpm(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_reg_price1'));
dpm(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_sale_price2')));

Comment: Hi Neo, thanks so much for your quickly reply. Been testing almost immediately, getting the same results as before, same Warning on empty fields. Using the code you gave, with only 2 fields (e.g., $howmany and $price1) works as before with computed value appearing correctly. I get the same error when I add a 3rd variable that is an empty field - and the results shows 0, most likely due the multiplication with empty field.

Comment: modified the code. Please see if this works.

Comment: Same results, same Warning. Works fine with just 2 fields, computed value - great. As soon as I add a 3rd, get the error and 0 value.

Comment: ok I think I figured out the issue. the issue lies in the two array_pop s. In case of an empty field, the first array_pop returns null. And hence the second one gets null as parameter.

Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: On form submission, get a WSOD with Fatal error on line 1:
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/content/67/10793667/html/sites/all/modules/computed_field/computed_field.module(466) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Eureka. Not perfect, but works. Went back to the original code, changed last line. Still getting Warning on submission, but the calculation is working and shows up properly, even subtracted another variable $coupon.
I decided to try grouping variables using normal math formulas using "+" between each. 

$entity_field[0]['value'] = (($howmany*$price1) + ($howmany*$price2)) - $coupon;

Now that the variables are not being multiplied by a null value and there is value for one pair, I get the results, even if I still get the Warning. I guess I can turn off those. Thanks very much for your help.